# Microsoft Access Last modified date

Tags: ms-access, modified-date

I need to know when I last modified my database on microsoft access, but because I opened it today, it had changed the date. Is there a way to find out when I last modified it before hand?

Comment: Why don't you add a ModifiedDate to one of the most popular tables?

Answer (score 3):

Sort of, maybe. Look at system table MSysObjects. Find record with most recent date in DateUpdate field. Just do a quick sort Newest to Oldest. However, doesn't seem to track when general code modules are edited.

System tables are hidden by default. Unhide by right click on Navigation Page > All Access Objects > Navigation Options > select options.

or

In Access 2010 and later System tables can be made visible by going:

File > Options > Current Database > Navigation > Navigation Options... > Show System Objects

Or instead of unhiding, just build a query:
`SELECT * FROM MSysObjects ORDER BY DateUpdate DESC;`